# In orient db property value stored as _NOT_PARSED_

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, orientdb

I want to store stringified json in database before store I stringify data and pass it to store in database. It works locally fine but not working with staging environment. Can anybody help me to sort out this problem

This is how stored in database:

```
[{"Form":"Abc","Product":"AB-456456","PM":"DEF"}, _NOT_PARSED_, _NOT_PARSED_]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually problem with orientdb.
I was trying to store stringyfied objects in array and store that array as string(but passed array as it is).with orientdb 2 it works fine. With orient db 3 it is not parsing array value to string instead storing value _NOT_PARSED_.